# Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock. Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, nfs

I trying to run mongodb statefulset with three replicas in kubernetes using nfs persistence storage. Out of three pods mongo-0 pod is in running and another two pods are showing `CrashLoopBackOff`. I saw the logs of those two pods and getting the error like

> 2018-11-27T21:38:18.581+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Unknown error). Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating

Here the [link](https://github.com/BalipalliGayathri/Mongosfs-nfs/tree/master) for my pv, pvc and mongodb statefulset files.

Could anybody suggest me on this issue?

Comment: How are you starting the mongod instances? Are you setting the --replSet and --bind_ip options? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

Comment: Hello Bajal. yes, I am using the stateful set on kubernetes cluster here, As i provided in the link, i configured the --bind_ip as 0.0.0.0.   how could i configure --replSet and --bind_ip options? Is there any alternative ways for that? Would you please suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

kill mongod processes 
in ubuntu
sudo killall -9 mongod
or

ps -aux|grep mongo
kill -9 [PID]
PID of mongod

Comment: I am killing the process of mongo. but it is showing on another process ID.